# Интерфейс PyQT отличается на разных устройствах

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Есть интерфейс, который прекрасно отображается на компьютере, но при запуске на ноутбуке всё иначе. Текст по ощущения выходит за виджет, некоторые объекты отображаются некорректно. Насколько я понимаю, дело не в разрешении, так как на компьютере и ноутбуке оно одинаковое. Как это можно исправить?

[image: Часть интерфейса]

В интерфейсе слишком много строк кода, поэтому отправлю ссылку на яндекс диск с проектом.
[ссылка на яндекс диск с проектом](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/5fUx21JEbxHDVA)

Comment: charodey_308, пожалуйста, предоставьте код, запустив который, можно получить окно, которое вы предоставили на изображении.

Comment: Масштабирование проверь.

Comment: Я, например, не вижу  яндекс диск, а вот github.com вижу

Answer (score 0):

Что значит "на компьютере" и "на ноутбуке"? Если на ПК и лэптопе стоят разные операционные системы, например windows 10 и ubuntu gnome - то pyqt gui будет выглядеть по разному в windows и в linux. Если же и там и там стоит например, win10 - то скорее всего проблема в разной версии pyqt или pyside.

Comment: Версии одинаковые. Версии PyQt тоже одинаковые.